# Cannot make bind9 forward DNS query to subdomain unless recursive enabled

Tags: bind

I am trying to develop my own dynamic DNS. I'm running my own custom DNS for the subdomain on port 5353. ASCII diagram:

```
INET --->:53 Bind 9 --->:5353 node.js
               |
               V
           zone_files
```

I have example.com. The node.js DNS is for dyn.example.com.

In my /etc/bind/named.conf.local I have:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.com.example";
    allow-transfer {
        zonetxfrsafe;
    };
};

zone "dyn.example.com" IN {
    # DYNAMIC
    type forward;
    forwarders { 127.0.0.1 port 5353; };
    forward only;
};
```

I've even gone so far as to add a NS in my example.com zone file:

```
$TTL    86400
@   IN  SOA ns.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
            2013070104  ; Serial
               7200     ; Refresh
               1200     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
              86400 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
        NS  ns                    ; inet of our nameserver

ns      A   1.2.3.4

; NS record for subdomain
dyn     NS  ns
```

When I attempt to get a record from the subdomain server it doesn't get forwarded:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 test.dyn.example.com
```

However if I turn recursive on in /etc/bind/named.conf.options:

```
options {
  recursion yes;
}
```

.. then I CAN see the request going to the subdomain server.

But I **don't want** `recursion yes;` in my Bind configuration as it is poor security practice (and allows all-and-sundry requests that are not related to my managed zones).

How does one forward (proxy) zone queries for just one zone? Or do I give up on Bind altogether and find a DNS server that can actually forward specific queries?

Comment: When you get a chance, can you accept my answer so that this no longer shows up on the list of unanswered question?

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. Query forwarding *is* a form of recursion, and this is behaving as expected.

You must either set up your dynamic DNS as its own discrete nameserver, or perform zone transfers off of it.

Comment: f@#$ - looks like I'm going to have to write my own nameserver from scratch.